# How can I fetch all records from cloudkit

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I am having trouble getting my application to fetch all of one type of record and have each users record put into an array.

this is the code that saves the record

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   let id = CKRecordID(recordName: "01")
   let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location", recordID: id)
   locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
   let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
   publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
     //..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use a `CKQuery` with a `NSPredicate` set to true:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "location", predicate: predicate)

database?.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
    //...
}
```

Comment: According to CKQuery API Reference: "Predicates are based on a format string. You cannot use value or block-based predicates." I don't think it was always like this, but currently this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];

CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Group_attributes"];

[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil:^(NSArray *results,error){

}];
```

Comment: According to CKQuery API Reference: "Predicates are based on a format string. You cannot use value or block-based predicates." I don't think it was always like this, but currently this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:ckEventsRecord predicate:predicate];

```
[[CloudKitManager publicCloudDatabase] performQuery:query
                            inZoneWithID:nil
                       completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"%@",results);
                           NSLog(@"%@",error);

                            [arrTemp addObjectsFromArray:results];




                           }];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.